# Fee Challan as a practice in Java Swing,

Tags: java, beginner, swing

I have made three classes and I have put all the UI code in a different class and used method for labels, text fields etc so it does not mix up. Please look into this code and tell me is it good approach?.

The UI is complete but the i just started working on functionality and was getting nowhere. The thing I want to do is fill the form and it just prints the form after I hit print button.

This is my first time using Swing and I wanted some wisdom from you guys to further this practice.

**OUTPUT**

[image: Resulting UI screenshot]

When I type text into the first column the other column must fill up on their own so I don't have to type again and again.

**StudentDetails.java**

```
public class StudentDetails {

    private final String CREDITNUMBER = "1234567891011121";
    private String fullName, grade, section, totalRupeesInWords, nameOfSchool, addressOfSchool, phoneNumber, copyOfSlip,
    bankName, bankAddress, bankAccountType;

    private double tuition, annual, securityMoney, admission, arrears, totalRupeesInFigures;
    private String[] noteToParents;

    StudentDetails() {
    }

    StudentDetails(String fullName, String grade, String section, String totalRupeesInWords,      String nameOfSchool, String addressOfSchool,
               String phoneNumber, String copyOfSlip, String bankName, String bankAddress, String bankAccountType,
               String[] noteToParents, double tuition, double annual, double securityMoney, double admission,
               double arrears, double totalRupeesInFigures) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
    this.grade = grade;
    this.section = section;
    this.totalRupeesInWords = totalRupeesInWords;
    this.nameOfSchool = nameOfSchool;
    this.addressOfSchool = addressOfSchool;
    this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    this.copyOfSlip = copyOfSlip;
    this.bankName = bankName;
    this.bankAddress = bankAddress;
    this.bankAccountType = bankAccountType;
    this.tuition = tuition;
    this.annual = annual;
    this.securityMoney = securityMoney;
    this.admission = admission;
    this.arrears = arrears;
    this.totalRupeesInFigures = totalRupeesInFigures;
    this.noteToParents = noteToParents;
    }

    public String getCREDITNUMBER() {
        return CREDITNUMBER;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public String getGrade() {
        return grade;
    }

    public void setGrade(String grade) {
        this.grade = grade;
    }

    public String getSection() {
        return section;
    }

    public void setSection(String section) {
        this.section = section;
    }

    public String getTotalRupeesInWords() {
        return totalRupeesInWords;
    }

    public void setTotalRupeesInWords(String totalRupeesInWords) {
        this.totalRupeesInWords = totalRupeesInWords;
    }

    public String getNameOfSchool() {
        return nameOfSchool;
    }

    public void setNameOfSchool(String nameOfSchool) {
        this.nameOfSchool = nameOfSchool;
    }

    public String getAddressOfSchool() {
        return addressOfSchool;
    }

    public void setAddressOfSchool(String addressOfSchool) {
        this.addressOfSchool = addressOfSchool;
    }

    public String getPhoneNumber() {
        return phoneNumber;
    }

    public void setPhoneNumber(String phoneNumber) {
        this.phoneNumber = phoneNumber;
    }

    public String getCopyOfSlip() {
        return copyOfSlip;
    }

    public void setCopyOfSlip(String copyOfSlip) {
        this.copyOfSlip = copyOfSlip;
    }

    public String getBankName() {
        return bankName;
    }

    public void setBankName(String bankName) {
        this.bankName = bankName;
    }

    public String getBankAddress() {
        return bankAddress;
    } 

    public void setBankAddress(String bankAddress) {
        this.bankAddress = bankAddress;
    }

    public String getBankAccountType() {
        return bankAccountType;
    }

    public void setBankAccountType(String bankAccountType) {
        this.bankAccountType = bankAccountType;
    }

    public double getTuition() {
        return tuition;
    }

    public void setTuition(double tuition) {
        this.tuition = tuition;
    }

    public double getAnnual() {
        return annual;
    }

    public void setAnnual(double annual) {
        this.annual = annual;
    }

    public double getSecurityMoney() {
        return securityMoney;
    }

    public void setSecurityMoney(double securityMoney) {
        this.securityMoney = securityMoney;
    }

    public double getAdmission() {
        return admission;
    }

    public void setAdmission(double admission) {
        this.admission = admission;
    }

    public double getArrears() {
        return arrears;
    }

    public void setArrears(double arrears) {
        this.arrears = arrears;
    }

    public double getTotalRupeesInFigures() {
        return totalRupeesInFigures;
    }

    public void setTotalRupeesInFigures(double totalRupeesInFigures) {
        this.totalRupeesInFigures = totalRupeesInFigures;
    }

    public String[] getNoteToParents() {
        return noteToParents;
    }

    public void setNoteToParents(String[] noteToParents) {
        this.noteToParents = noteToParents;
    }
}
```

**ProgramUI.java**

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class ProgramUI extends StudentDetails implements ActionListener {
JTextField fullNameInput, classInput, sectionInput, tuitionFeeInput, annualInput, securityInput, admissionInput,
        arrearsInput, totalRupeesInFiguresInput, totalRupeesInWordsInput;

    StudentDetails studentDetailsObject = new StudentDetails();

    private JFrame homePage;
    private JPanel homePagePanel;
    private JLabel logoImg, schoolNameLabel, schoolAddressLabel, schoolPhoneLabel, copyOfSlipLabel, bankNameLabel,
        bankAddressLabel, bankAccountTypeLabel, bankCreditNumberLabel, bankCreditNumberTextLabel, fullNameLabel, classLabel, sectionLabel,
        tuitionFeeLabel, annualLabel, securityLabel, admissionLabel, arrearsLabel, totalRupeesInFiguresLabel,
        totalRupeesInWordsLabel;

    ProgramUI() {
    }

    public ProgramUI(String fullName, String grade, String section, String totalRupeesInWords, String nameOfSchool, String addressOfSchool, String phoneNumber, String copyOfSlip, String bankName, String bankAddress, String bankAccountType, String[] noteToParents, double tuition, double annual, double securityMoney, double admission, double arrears, double totalRupeesInFigures, JFrame homePage, JPanel homePagePanel, JLabel logoImg, JLabel schoolNameLabel, JLabel schoolAddressLabel, JLabel schoolPhoneLabel, JLabel copyOfSlipLabel, JLabel bankNameLabel, JLabel bankAddressLabel, JLabel bankAccountTypeLabel, JLabel bankCreditNumberLabel, JLabel bankCreditNumberTextLabel, JLabel fullNameLabel, JLabel classLabel, JLabel sectionLabel, JLabel tuitionFeeLabel, JLabel annualLabel, JLabel securityLabel, JLabel admissionLabel, JLabel arrearsLabel, JLabel totalRupeesInFiguresLabel, JLabel totalRupeesInWordsLabel, JTextField fullNameInput, JTextField classInput, JTextField sectionInput, JTextField tuitionFeeInput, JTextField annualInput, JTextField securityInput, JTextField admissionInput, JTextField arrearsInput, JTextField totalRupeesInFiguresInput, JTextField totalRupeesInWordsInput) {
        super(fullName, grade, section, totalRupeesInWords, nameOfSchool, addressOfSchool, phoneNumber, copyOfSlip, bankName, bankAddress, bankAccountType, noteToParents, tuition, annual, securityMoney, admission, arrears, totalRupeesInFigures);
        this.homePage = homePage;
        this.homePagePanel = homePagePanel;
        this.logoImg = logoImg;
        this.schoolNameLabel = schoolNameLabel;
        this.schoolAddressLabel = schoolAddressLabel;
        this.schoolPhoneLabel = schoolPhoneLabel;
        this.copyOfSlipLabel = copyOfSlipLabel;
        this.bankNameLabel = bankNameLabel;
        this.bankAddressLabel = bankAddressLabel;
        this.bankAccountTypeLabel = bankAccountTypeLabel;
        this.bankCreditNumberLabel = bankCreditNumberLabel;
        this.bankCreditNumberTextLabel = bankCreditNumberTextLabel;
        this.fullNameLabel = fullNameLabel;
        this.classLabel = classLabel;
        this.sectionLabel = sectionLabel;
        this.tuitionFeeLabel = tuitionFeeLabel;
        this.annualLabel = annualLabel;
        this.securityLabel = securityLabel;
        this.admissionLabel = admissionLabel;
        this.arrearsLabel = arrearsLabel;
        this.totalRupeesInFiguresLabel = totalRupeesInFiguresLabel;
        this.totalRupeesInWordsLabel = totalRupeesInWordsLabel;
        this.fullNameInput = fullNameInput;
        this.classInput = classInput;
        this.sectionInput = sectionInput;
        this.tuitionFeeInput = tuitionFeeInput;
        this.annualInput = annualInput;
        this.securityInput = securityInput;
        this.admissionInput = admissionInput;
        this.arrearsInput = arrearsInput;
        this.totalRupeesInFiguresInput = totalRupeesInFiguresInput;
        this.totalRupeesInWordsInput = totalRupeesInWordsInput;
        }

    public void frameAndPanel() {
        // JFrame & JPanel
        homePage = new JFrame();
        homePage.setSize(1500, 800);
        homePagePanel = new JPanel();
        homePagePanel.setLayout(null);
        homePage.add(homePagePanel);

        // First Column labels
        labelsFirstColumn();
        settingLabelsFirstColumn();
        addingLabelsFirstColumn();

        // First Column text fields
        textFieldsFirstColumn();
        settingTextFieldsFirstColumn();
        addingTextFieldsFirstColumn();

        // First Separator
        firstSeparator();

        // Second Column labels
        labelsSecondColumn();
        settingLabelsSecondColumn();
        addingLabelsFirstColumn();

        // Second Column text fields
        textFieldsSecondColumn();
        settingTextFieldsSecondColumn();
        addingTextFieldsFirstColumn();

        // Second Separator
        secondSeparator();

        // Third Column labels
        labelsThirdColumn();
        settingLabelsThirdColumn();
        addingLabelsFirstColumn();

        // Third Column text fields
        textFieldsFirstColumn();
        settingTextFieldsThirdColumn();
        addingTextFieldsFirstColumn();

        button1();

        homePage.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        homePagePanel.setVisible(true);
        homePage.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void labelsFirstColumn() {
        logoImg = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("D:\\JavaProjects\\Challan\\src\\logo.jpeg"));
        schoolNameLabel = new JLabel("<html> &emsp &emsp &emsp ZAHEEN ACADEMY <html>");
        schoolAddressLabel = new JLabel("<html> D-60, BLOCK-9, K.D.A. SCHEME NO.5,<br/> &emsp &emsp &emsp CLIFTON KARACHI </html>");
        schoolPhoneLabel = new JLabel("<html> &emsp &emsp PH: 35874955 / 35820643 </html>");
        copyOfSlipLabel = new JLabel("<html> &emsp 1. PARENTS COPY OF FEE SLIP </html>");
        bankNameLabel = new JLabel("<html>&emsp &emsp &emsp ALLIED BANK LIMITED </html>");
        bankAddressLabel = new JLabel("Super Market, Clifton Branch, Karachi.");
        bankAccountTypeLabel = new JLabel("Current Account ");
        bankCreditNumberLabel = new JLabel(studentDetailsObject.getCREDITNUMBER());
        bankCreditNumberTextLabel = new JLabel("<html> &emsp &emsp Credit # </html>");
        fullNameLabel = new JLabel("Full Name: ");
        classLabel = new JLabel("Class: ");
        sectionLabel = new JLabel("Section: ");
        tuitionFeeLabel = new JLabel("Tuition Fee: ");
        annualLabel = new JLabel("Annual: ");
        securityLabel = new JLabel("Security: ");
        admissionLabel = new JLabel("Admission: ");
        arrearsLabel = new JLabel("Arrears: ");
        totalRupeesInFiguresLabel = new JLabel("<html> Total Rupees </br> in Figures: </html>");
        totalRupeesInWordsLabel = new JLabel("<html> Total Rupees </br> in Words: </html>");
        // = new JLabel("Note to Parents: ");
    }

    public void settingLabelsFirstColumn() {
        logoImg.setBounds(30, 20, 60, 60);
        schoolNameLabel.setBounds(100, 20, 350, 20);
        schoolAddressLabel.setBounds(100, 40, 350, 40);
        schoolPhoneLabel.setBounds(100, 80, 300, 20);
        copyOfSlipLabel.setBounds(100, 100, 300, 20);
        bankNameLabel.setBounds(100, 120, 300, 20);
        bankAddressLabel.setBounds(100, 140, 300, 20);
        bankAccountTypeLabel.setBounds(100, 160, 300, 20);
        bankCreditNumberLabel.setBounds(210, 170, 120, 20);
        bankCreditNumberLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        bankCreditNumberTextLabel.setBounds(100, 180, 120, 20);

        fullNameLabel.setBounds(70, 240, 300, 20);
        classLabel.setBounds(70, 280, 100, 20);
        sectionLabel.setBounds(70, 320, 100, 20);
        tuitionFeeLabel.setBounds(70, 360, 100, 20);
        annualLabel.setBounds(70, 400, 100, 20);
        securityLabel.setBounds(70, 440, 100, 20);
        admissionLabel.setBounds(70, 480, 100, 20);
        arrearsLabel.setBounds(70, 520, 100, 20);
        totalRupeesInFiguresLabel.setBounds(70, 560, 100, 40);
        totalRupeesInWordsLabel.setBounds(70, 620, 100, 40);
    }

    public void addingLabelsFirstColumn() {
        homePagePanel.add(logoImg);
        homePagePanel.add(schoolNameLabel);
        homePagePanel.add(schoolAddressLabel);
        homePagePanel.add(schoolPhoneLabel);
        homePagePanel.add(copyOfSlipLabel);
        homePagePanel.add(bankNameLabel);
        homePagePanel.add(bankAddressLabel);
        homePagePanel.add(bankAccountTypeLabel);
        homePagePanel.add(bankCreditNumberLabel);
        homePagePanel.add(bankCreditNumberTextLabel);
        homePagePanel.add(fullNameLabel);
        homePagePanel.add(classLabel);
        homePagePanel.add(sectionLabel);
        homePagePanel.add(tuitionFeeLabel);
        homePagePanel.add(annualLabel);
        homePagePanel.add(securityLabel);
        homePagePanel.add(admissionLabel);
        homePagePanel.add(arrearsLabel);
        homePagePanel.add(totalRupeesInFiguresLabel);
        homePagePanel.add(totalRupeesInWordsLabel);
    }


    public void labelsSecondColumn() {
        labelsFirstColumn();
        copyOfSlipLabel.setText("<html> &emsp 2. BANK COPY OF FEE SLIP </html>");
        sectionLabel.hide();
        tuitionFeeLabel.hide();
        annualLabel.hide();
        securityLabel.hide();
        admissionLabel.hide();
        arrearsLabel.hide();
    }

    public void settingLabelsSecondColumn() {
        logoImg.setBounds(530, 20, 60, 60);
        schoolNameLabel.setBounds(600, 20, 350, 20);
        schoolAddressLabel.setBounds(600, 40, 350, 40);
        schoolPhoneLabel.setBounds(600, 80, 300, 20);
        copyOfSlipLabel.setBounds(600, 100, 300, 20);
        bankNameLabel.setBounds(600, 120, 300, 20);
        bankAddressLabel.setBounds(600, 140, 300, 20);
        bankAccountTypeLabel.setBounds(600, 160, 300, 20);
        bankCreditNumberLabel.setBounds(710, 170, 120, 20);
        bankCreditNumberLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        bankCreditNumberTextLabel.setBounds(600, 180, 300, 20);

        fullNameLabel.setBounds(570, 240, 100, 20);
        classLabel.setBounds(570, 280, 100, 20);
        totalRupeesInFiguresLabel.setBounds(570, 320, 100, 40);
        totalRupeesInWordsLabel.setBounds(570, 380, 100, 40);
    }

    public void labelsThirdColumn() {
        labelsFirstColumn();
        copyOfSlipLabel.setText("<html> &emsp 2. SCHOOL'S COPY OF FEE SLIP </html>");
    }

    public void settingLabelsThirdColumn() {
        logoImg.setBounds(1030, 20, 60, 60);
        schoolNameLabel.setBounds(1100, 20, 350, 20);
        schoolAddressLabel.setBounds(1100, 40, 350, 40);
        schoolPhoneLabel.setBounds(1100, 80, 300, 20);
        copyOfSlipLabel.setBounds(1100, 100, 300, 20);
        bankNameLabel.setBounds(1100, 120, 300, 20);
        bankAddressLabel.setBounds(1100, 140, 300, 20);
        bankAccountTypeLabel.setBounds(1100, 160, 300, 20);
        bankCreditNumberLabel.setBounds(1210, 170, 120, 20);
        bankCreditNumberLabel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));
        bankCreditNumberTextLabel.setBounds(1100, 180, 300, 20);

        fullNameLabel.setBounds(1070, 240, 100, 20);
        classLabel.setBounds(1070, 280, 100, 20);
        sectionLabel.setBounds(1070, 320, 100, 20);
        tuitionFeeLabel.setBounds(1070, 360, 100, 20);
        annualLabel.setBounds(1070, 400, 100, 20);
        securityLabel.setBounds(1070, 440, 100, 20);
        admissionLabel.setBounds(1070, 480, 100, 20);
        arrearsLabel.setBounds(1070, 520, 100, 20);
        totalRupeesInFiguresLabel.setBounds(1070, 560, 100, 40);
        totalRupeesInWordsLabel.setBounds(1070, 620, 100, 40);
    }

    public void textFieldsFirstColumn() {
        fullNameInput = new JTextField(1);
        classInput = new JTextField(1);
        sectionInput = new JTextField(1);
        tuitionFeeInput = new JTextField(1);
        annualInput = new JTextField(1);
        securityInput = new JTextField(1);
        admissionInput = new JTextField(1);
        arrearsInput = new JTextField(1);
        totalRupeesInFiguresInput = new JTextField(1);
        totalRupeesInWordsInput = new JTextField(1);
    }

    public void settingTextFieldsFirstColumn() {
        fullNameInput.setBounds(170, 240, 250, 25);
        classInput.setBounds(170, 280, 250, 25);
        sectionInput.setBounds(170, 320, 250, 25);
        tuitionFeeInput.setBounds(170, 360, 250, 25);
        annualInput.setBounds(170, 400, 250, 25);
        securityInput.setBounds(170, 440, 250, 25);
        admissionInput.setBounds(170, 480, 250, 25);
        arrearsInput.setBounds(170, 520, 250, 25);
        totalRupeesInFiguresInput.setBounds(170, 570, 250, 25);
        totalRupeesInWordsInput.setBounds(170, 630, 250, 25);
    }

    public void addingTextFieldsFirstColumn() {
        homePagePanel.add(fullNameInput);
        homePagePanel.add(classInput);
        homePagePanel.add(sectionInput);
        homePagePanel.add(tuitionFeeInput);
        homePagePanel.add(annualInput);
        homePagePanel.add(securityInput);
        homePagePanel.add(admissionInput);
        homePagePanel.add(arrearsInput);
        homePagePanel.add(totalRupeesInFiguresInput);
        homePagePanel.add(totalRupeesInWordsInput);
    }

    public void textFieldsSecondColumn() {
        textFieldsFirstColumn();
        sectionInput.hide();
        tuitionFeeInput.hide();
        annualInput.hide();
        securityInput.hide();
        admissionInput.hide();
        arrearsInput.hide();
     }

    public void settingTextFieldsSecondColumn() {
        fullNameInput.setBounds(670, 240, 250, 25);
        classInput.setBounds(670, 280, 250, 25);
        totalRupeesInFiguresInput.setBounds(670, 330, 250, 25);
        totalRupeesInWordsInput.setBounds(670, 390, 250, 25);
    }

    public void settingTextFieldsThirdColumn() {
        fullNameInput.setBounds(1170, 240, 250, 25);
        classInput.setBounds(1170, 280, 250, 25);
        sectionInput.setBounds(1170, 320, 250, 25);
        tuitionFeeInput.setBounds(1170, 360, 250, 25);
        annualInput.setBounds(1170, 400, 250, 25);
        securityInput.setBounds(1170, 440, 250, 25);
        admissionInput.setBounds(1170, 480, 250, 25);
        arrearsInput.setBounds(1170, 520, 250, 25);
        totalRupeesInFiguresInput.setBounds(1170, 570, 250, 25);
        totalRupeesInWordsInput.setBounds(1170, 630, 250, 25);
    }

    public void firstSeparator() {
        JSeparator firstVerticalSeparator = new JSeparator();
        firstVerticalSeparator.setOrientation(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
        firstVerticalSeparator.setBounds(500, 0, 50, 800);
        homePagePanel.add(firstVerticalSeparator);

    }

    public void secondSeparator() {
        JSeparator secondVerticalSeparator = new JSeparator();
        secondVerticalSeparator.setOrientation(SwingConstants.VERTICAL);
        secondVerticalSeparator.setBounds(1000, 0, 50, 800);
        homePagePanel.add(secondVerticalSeparator);

   }

    public void button1() {
        Button button = new Button("PRINT");
        button.addActionListener(this);
        button.setBounds(100, 700, 50, 30);
        homePagePanel.add(button);
    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String fullNameSave = fullNameInput.getText();
        studentDetailsObject.setFullName(fullNameSave);
        fullNameInput.setText(getFullName());
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ProgramUI programUI = new ProgramUI();
        programUI.frameAndPanel();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man,

I did not knew much about that website.

Comment: Oracle has a helpful tutorial, [Creating a GUI With Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/index.html).  Skip the Learning Swing with the NetBeans IDE section.

Comment: note: it's utterly __wrong__ to do any manual sizing/locating - instead find and use a LayoutManager that suits your requirements